# can someone help me with this contact validation form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Ok I need to make this contact form highlight red and say not valid inside the boxes! What ever I do I can't get it to work! I can't change the HTML tags that are already there you can add to the HTML but not delete any of it but I want it to display on the same page with JavaScript and have it look very nice can someone edit what I have and help me make this work please!

Oh and I keep getting 2 emails every time I test it also!

Here is there HTML:

```
        <!-- Contact -->
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-style4">
            <article id="contact">
                <header>
                    <h2>Want to hire me? Get in touch!</h2>
                    <span>I do quality work and would love to work for you!.</span>
                </header>
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                        <div id="errors"></div>
                            <form method='post' action='mailform.php' id='contact-form'>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <a href="#" class="button form-button-submit">Send Message</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="button button-alt form-button-reset">Clear Form</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <!-- Contact -->
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-style4">
            <article id="contact">
                <header>
                    <h2>Want to hire me? Get in touch!</h2>
                    <span>I do quality work and would love to work for you!.</span>
                </header>
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                        <div id="errors"></div>
                            <form method='post' action='mailform.php' id='contact-form'>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row half">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <a href="#" class="button form-button-submit">Send Message</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="button button-alt form-button-reset">Clear Form</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I need the JavaScript here:

```
    <script>

    </script>
```

And the PHP form is here:

```
    <?php
$to = "bcw1995@gmail.com";
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail($_REQUEST['email'], $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  }
  header("Location: http://www.thorbis.com/#contact");
?>
```

Can someone please fix this you will be a life saver!

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of JS frameworks around that will help.

Comment: What do you mean by not valid? Please add your requirements like blank fields, or special format, etc.

Comment: use any of following js library for form validation http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/ http://validatorjs.org/ http://parsleyjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

**You get two E-Mails:**

Your  mail is send twice, because you are calling two times the mail() function. Delete this line `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

// EDIT

change the second E-Mail function to this: `mail($to, $subject, $message, "From:" . $email);`
Else the sender will get the email that he has send.

**Validation:**

There are a lot of ways and librarys for a Javascript Form-Validation. I recommand jQuery + jQuery.Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).
But i would also add a validation in the PHP file, because if somebody has disabled javascript, he can send empty emails.

I hope that i could help you.